# How can I turn a json object into a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

So, I need to convert a json object like this `{"0":"sometext","1":"someothertext"}` into a javascript array with the index matching the integer and the data at the index the string. I tried using JSON.parse() but it didn't work since this happens.

```
var json = '{"0":"sometext","1":"someothertext"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
//Then when I would want to assign a part of the object to a variable this gives me an error
var somevar = obj.0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate over every property in the object and assign them as values in the array:

```
var obj = {"0":"sometext","1":"someothertext"};
var arr = [];

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    arr[key] = obj[key]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket notation:

Change

```
var somevar = obj.0;
```

to

```
var somevar = obj[0];
```